# Why does this object display function even if I haven't explicitly used plt.show function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
z = plt.subplots(2,2)
z
```

Then the output is as follows :

```
>> (<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x28409ef3a90>,
 array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000028409F810B8>,
         <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000002840A163B00>],
        [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000002840A1D71D0>,
         <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000002840A237518>]], dtype=object))
```

Since `z[0]` is an Figure object, I expected `<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x28409ef3a90>` to be the output if I run `z[0]`. But it displays 2x2 plot even if I haven't used `display.show()` explicitly! Why does such thing happen?

Comment: Are you using IPython?

Comment: @user2357112 Yes! But I haven't used any magic commands in the code!

Answer (score 0):

iPython outputs the `repr` value of the object `z` in the output space.
in this case, a matplotlib `Figure` object.

iPython does this when the last line executed is simply the object (not an assignment)